# XGBoost error: /workspace/src/metric/elementwise_metric.cc:28: Check failed: preds.size() == info.labelsSize() (

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I am new to machine learning and trying to solve a problem of housing prices of kaggle competition.. i am trying to run this code and fit this model but outputs a error..please help and explain as i am a novice...thank in  advance

I tried to search in google but shows multiclass error don't know what it is and shows the solution as a "mlogloss" or "merror"

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from learntools.core import *
from xgboost import XGBRegressor


iowa_file_path = '../input/train.csv'

home_data = pd.read_csv(iowa_file_path)

y = home_data.SalePrice

features = ['LotArea', 'YearBuilt', '1stFlrSF', '2ndFlrSF', 'FullBath', 
'BedroomAbvGr', 'TotRmsAbvGrd']
X = home_data[features]


train_X, val_X, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=1)


iowa_model = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=1000,learning_rate=0.05)

iowa_model.fit(train_X, train_y,early_stopping_rounds=5,eval_set= 
[(train_X,val_y)],verbose=False)
```

Comment: can you post your error message?

Comment: try iowa_model.fit(train_X, train_y,early_stopping_rounds=5,eval_set= 
[(val_X,val_y)],verbose=False)

Comment: thanku it worked@YongkangZhao

Comment: awesome :) glad I can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you got a 'typo' try

```
iowa_model.fit(train_X, train_y,early_stopping_rounds=5,eval_set= [(val_X,val_y)],verbose=False)
```